Book where lone man stops at car crash and finds a fatally injured woman just about to have a baby. She looks like his dead wife
Man stops to help with a car crash at night, finds a fatally injured pregnant woman who looks like his wife, but she died years ago. The woman has the ability to plant suggestions in peoples minds so they will help her. There is a secret society nearby who were waiting for her child to be born to open a 'portal' of some type, but she escaped before she had the baby. Her daughter is then born and she makes the man promise to protect her.
A bit more info: The baby grows extremely fast, so in a matter of weeks, she is a child. She also has the ability to place 'suggestions' in other peoples heads, including making a farmer think she is his grand daughter so that she and the man, can stay at the farmers home. However, every time she uses this 'power' the secret society is able to track her and so it becomes a chase through the country (UK).

Which year (approximately) did you read this book?

I think it was at least 7 years +.
